# IOS - installing enterprise provisioning profile or enterprise signed app require callback to Apple?

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning, provisioning-profile

All:

My employer believes they have a legal loophole to distribute Enterprise signed apps to our customers, but I'm uncertain it will be technically feasable. ( We are in the infancy of IOS in our enviroment)

> "Internal Use Applications developed under [the Apple Enterprise Agreement] may be deployed on Deployment Devices in two ways: (1) deployment for internal use by Employees, and **(2) deployment for use by Customers either on Your physical premises**  or under the direct supervision and physical control of Your Employees in other locations, subject to Apple’s right to review and approve such deployment as set forth herein. The App Store approval process is not required."

In our case, it is true -- customers will be on our remote physical site.  (Personally, I believe clause 2 is really intended for corporate-provided devices to a customer -- think museums, etc, or contractors, and that even if this is a loophole, is one that is likely to be locked down. But that is moot for now.)

Our location are without cellular service is not available, AND where we provide the only available Wifi which is restricted to our intranet-- we do not allow not customers free internet access, except at very expensive cost to the customer which we do not wish to do here).  So, the idea was to locally host the app (IPA) and profile in our local LAN, have the customer install a Enterprise provisioning profile, and then install our apps from a local source.

So my question is if this TECHNICALLY feasable --- Is is possible to install a povisioning profile over the air (Wifi) WITHOUT calling back to Apple?.  And if so, can a Enterprise signed app also be installed, again without calling back to Apple.   Does an end user get anything more scary than a "Do you want to install MegaCorps Enterprise Provisoning Profile on your device"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow for installing apps from a secure web page. Just follow the directions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

It's in the section *In-house apps* > *Deploying apps* > *Installing apps wirelessly*. Apple doesn't say anything about needing to add individual UDIDs to the provisioning profile. I think they don't want to make a big deal of it lest misuse becoming rampant.

I don't have any legal advice, though.